# Can we standardize a numerical column which actually is categorical?

Tags: python, lasso-regression, regularized

I have the House Prices - Advanced Regression Techniques Data set. I need to do Lasso and Ridge Regularization on it. I saved the train data in the variable named house. Typed the following code:

```
house.info()
```

Got this output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYUtO.png)

There are columns in this data set which are numerical(int64 and float 64) but they actually are categorical(both ordinal and nominal).

I wanted to ask whether I can standardize these categorical variables or should I first convert all these variables into type "object" using `house[col_name]=house[col_name].astype(str)` and then do one- hot encoding on these variables and standardize the rest of the numerical columns?

Answer (score 0):

When a column is cardinal it is possible to apply one-hot-encoding, in this way the categorical columns can be vectorized in a binary way for each category.

```
import pandas as pd


raw_df= pd.get_dummies(data=raw_df, 
                       cardinal_features=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], 
                       prefix=['feature1_', 'feature2_',  'feature3_'])
```

Comment: Yes, I have used one hot encoding to ordinal categorical variables which consists of string values.
But I have standardized using standardscaler() for ordinal and nominal variables which consists numerical values. Rather than hot encoding all of the categorical variables.
 In doing so, I got better model metrics.

Comment: I think the model could be overfitted, cardinal variables are discrete random variables. `StandardScaler()` is to approximate a continuous variable distribution to a normal standard distribution with mean `0` and variance `1`.

Comment: Oh okay, my model though didn't overfit. But I got a fair idea. Thanks

Comment: Yes, another option could be to get ratios for each category as a metric